# Traveling from Mexico to Amman; do I need a transit visa for CDG or LHR?

Tags: visas, transit, uk, france, jordanian-citizens

I am a Jordanian citizen living in Mexico. I will be traveling from Mexico to Amman, Jordan. Do I need a transit visa for CDG or LHR? I have less than a 24 hour layover.

Answer (score 4):

You won't need a visa for a brief airside transit at either airport (however, I am not sure about the maximum duration for the layover, if any). For Heathrow, see [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/jordan/transit/no). For Charles-de-Gaulle, the rules are detailed in [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

The reason for the difference between France and Germany you noted in the comments is that Jordan is not in the Schengen-wide list of countries whose citizens require an “airport transit visa” (they do in any case require a regular Schengen visa to *enter* any Schengen country). But Schengen member states can also add countries to that list (that's one of the few provisions that allow different Schengen member states to apply slightly different rules). According to the EU Commission website, Germany and the Czech Republic (but not France) do require airport transit visas for Jordanian citizens.

Comment: He needs one for Germany & we are having a REALLY hard time with the German embassy in Mexico City. They don't answer the phone, you can only call between 2:30-3:00 for questions about visas. He already flew there at a cost of $400 to be turned away at door because he scheduled the wrong type of appt. His current ticket is through Frankfurt.

Comment: @kathleen Yes, that's correct, a visa is required for Jordanian citizens for airside transit in Germany and the Czech Republic (see the other question) but not in France so if you are able to change your ticket, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, we booked with Lufthansa & all of their flights go through Germany. I am going to see if we can change the ticket to something my son & I can use next year & he is just going to start all over with a new ticket. What a fiasco.

Comment: You have been very helpful so I will ask you this as I find the answers on some of the other sites very confusing. Do US citizens need to apply for tourist Visas in advance or do we just fill out on the plane like I do when  go to Mexico?  I did not need one for UK.

Comment: @kathleen US citizens do not need a visa for short stays in the Schengen area either.

Comment: According to this, France is part of the Schengen area, so wouldn't he need transient visa?   http://www.axa-schengen.com/en/schengen-visa-countries

Comment: @kathleen Not sure I understand your point. France is indeed in the Schengen area but the US is not in the list of countries whose citizens require a visa to enter the Schengen area. In any case, it would be best to ask another question or come to [the travel chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: The point isn't about me, US citizen, CDG, it is for my BF, JOrdanian citizen. We just want to be sure as the websites are confusing & he has already lost o much money trying to fix this.

Comment: @kathleen I must have misunderstood your previous comment, sorry for the confusion. Both countries are indeed in the Schengen area but the rules for airport transit can be slightly different from one country to the next. Rules for visits are the same across the area but differ from transit rules. To recap: US citizens can enter or transit in France, Germany and everywhere else in the Schengen area, no visa needed. Jordanian citizens can transit without a visa in a French airport but not in a German airport. They cannot enter the Schengen area (including France and Germany) without a visa.

Comment: @kathleen I amended my answer to clarify all that.